# Domino method ViewNavigator createViewNavFromCategory(String categoryName) returns navigator with no entries when used with many sub categories

Tags: servlets, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a java servlet that works as a REST service. My data is delivered through a categorized view with 3 categorized columns.

I create a view navigator using the View.createViewNavFromCategory("2014\43") where the category specified adheres to the first two categorized columns.

2014 = year and 43 = week number, which means there can be up to 53 second column categories.

My categorized columns are sorted decending. For some strange reason **I found that all columns had to be sorted the same way** (undocumented).

My code:

```
        String viewCategory = "";
        if (isYearSpecified) viewCategory = <year parameter>;
        if (isWeekSpecified) viewCategory = viewCategory + "\\" + <week parameter>;
        ViewNavigator nav = lookupView.createViewNavFromCategory(viewCategory);

        //and set the size of the preloading cache: 
        nav.setBufferMaxEntries(numCacheEntries); 

        // Initialize list of JSON income objects
        List prognosisJSON = new ArrayList();

        //and then traverse the view: 
        ViewEntry currEntry = nav.getFirst();
```

This works as a charm until I specify a week **lower than 13**. If using category "2014\12", "2014\11" and lower the **viewEntry returns null** when trying to access the first entry in the navigator.

I should perhaps add that my view contains 2102 documents in categories before the one that fails (if there is an undocumented max limit).

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: What version ofd Domino is this?

Comment: Hi Richard. I'm using Domino 9.0.1 FP3.

Comment: There's a wiki doc from (I think) 8.5.3 that describes some caching capabilities in NotesViewNavigator.  Unfortunately the link doesn't seem to be working rigfht now. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Fast_Retrieval_of_View_Data_Using_the_ViewNavigator_Cache   From what I can pick up from pages that link to it, there's a property NotesViewNavigator.BufferMaxEntries. Perhaps playing with that value might help you.

Comment: I'have tried the BufferMaxEntries already. I had it set to 400 and tried to double this just to check if it made any difference. Unfortunately it didn't...

Comment: I just tested accessing the samt view category using Lotusscript. No problem there...

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug that you might need to talk to IBM about, unless someone else has a workaround...

Comment: Maybe a workaround is to use a vector to get the first entry under that category view.getEntryByKey() and then use that in view.createViewNavFrom() to start with. With view.getEntryByKey you could specify a Vector, which may solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks Ferry. I will try and update here with my findings.

Comment: Ove, wild guess, try adding a letter after the number, and see if it fails for 2014\12a the same way it fails for 2014\12.  When  you get this working, I hope you blog about it as it looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I would never have guessed that it's possible to use createViewNavFromCategory to search a view with multiple categorized columns, using a key with a *backslash* as category separator. I'd expected an array or Vector parameter... For anyone passing by: is it documented somewhere??

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're hitting this problem http://www.intec.co.uk/apparent-java-getalldocumentsbykey-getallentriesbykey-bug/. The fact it works in LotusScript and the keys you're looking for sound suspicious. To completely confirm it, it should also fail in a Java agent.
The latest I had was that this was planned for 9.0.2.
If so, in the mean time, changing the columns to text instead of number will solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using text already, @Text(@Year(Date)) and @Text(WeekNr). But (and I can see that there is a BUT here), since @Text-ify the week number column will break the sorting I have inserted a hidden sort column (with WeekNr only). Tonight I will scrap this column and insert a leading '0' for the weeks 1 to 9. That should fix the sorting.

And, as I stated in earlier comment', my Lotusscript agent is able to create a navigator with content where the java fails...

Comment: Unfortunately the issue I found and mentioned on my blog is an issue with the core Java API which pre-dates XPages.